# Dealing with programmatically added form elements

Tags: angular

I am working on a component that allows the user to dynamically add a new form element. The code available here and below https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h3tmfe. I have two questions:

1) How do I check that the form element is not empty before adding a new row?

2) How do I access the value in the form element programmatically?

i.e. if the output of `{{invoiceForm.value | json}}` is the below, how would I access "item 1"? i.e. invoiceForm.itemRows(0).value or something?

```
{
  "itemRows": [
    {
      "itemname": "item 1"
    },
    {
      "itemname": "item 2"
    }
  ]
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
    <h3 class="page-header">Add Invoice</h3>
    <button type="button" (click)="addNewRow()" class="btn btn-primary">Add new Row</button><br>
    <form [formGroup]="invoiceForm">
      <div formArrayName="itemRows">
        <div *ngFor="let itemrow of invoiceForm.controls.itemRows.controls; let i=index"  [formGroupName]="i">
          <h4>Invoice Row #{{ i + 1 }}</h4>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Item Name</label>
            <input formControlName="itemname" class="form-control">
          </div>
          <button *ngIf="invoiceForm.controls.itemRows.controls.length > 1" (click)="deleteRow(i)" class="btn btn-danger">Delete Button</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </form>
    <pre>{{invoiceForm.value | json}}</pre>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormArray, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  public invoiceForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private _fb: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.invoiceForm = this._fb.group({
      itemRows: this._fb.array([this.initItemRows()])
    });
  }

  get formArr() {
    return this.invoiceForm.get('itemRows') as FormArray;
  }

  initItemRows() {
    return this._fb.group({
      itemname: ['']
    });
  }

  addNewRow() {
    this.formArr.push(this.initItemRows());
  }

  deleteRow(index: number) {
    this.formArr.removeAt(index);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the Form array values using

```
this.formArr.value
```

To check if the previous field is not empty

```
if (this.formArr.value[this.formArr.value.length-1].itemname !== ""){
  this.formArr.push(this.initItemRows());
} else {
  //display warning
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This piece of code helps you to check form is valid or not before adding/pushing a new row.

```
 addNewRow() {
    this.isClicked = true;
    const itemFormCtrl = this.invoiceForm.controls['itemRows'];
    if (itemFormCtrl.valid) {
      this.formArr.push(this.initItemRows());
      this.isClicked = false;
    }
  }
```

Here is updated [`StackBlitz`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gwaetd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)